# Thread-safe iteration over key set of a synchronized map

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

Somewhere in my multi-threaded code I have a map (which gets accessed by multiple threads) declared like this:

```
private Map<Foo, Integer> fooMap =
    Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Foo, Integer>());
```

The same class exposes a public method

```
public Collection<Foo> getFooList() {
    return fooMap.keySet();
}
```

Somewhere else in my code I iterate over the collection returned by `getFooList()`. I am aware that most operations on a synchronized map are thread-safe, the one notable exception being iteration, which must be explicitly synchronized. I have implemented this in the following way:

```
synchronized(bar.getFooList()) {
    for (Foo foo : bar.getFooList()) {
        // do stuff with foo
    }
}
```

Every now and then I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` for the `for` statement. I am wondering whether I am synchronizing with the wrong class instance—should I synchronize with the map rather than its key set? Then again, I do not really want to expose the whole map to other classes (it is private for a reason).

How do I iterate over the key set in a thread-safe manner, without having to expose the entire map?

Comment: Try `getFooList().forEach(foo -> ...)` - this should hold internal lock on the key set until iterating is finished.

Comment: But don’t call a method `get…List` when it actually returns a `Set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   map when iterating over any of its collection views:
>
> ```
>   Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
>       ...
>   Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
>       ...
>   synchronized (m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
>       Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>       while (i.hasNext())
>           foo(i.next());
>   }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic
>   behavior. The returned map will be serializable if the specified map
>   is serializable.

You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` which guarantees concurrency on `keySet`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()):

> The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never
>   throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse
>   elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may
>   (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to
>   construction.

Comment: Thanks, that explains at least why I am getting the `ConcurrentModificationException`. That leaves me with the second question: is there any way I can avoid exposing the map (as I don’t want other parts of the code to mess with it)?

Comment: @user149408. You can try `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is only useful, if the application logic can cope with the possibility of concurrent modifications, which may still happen and be reflected by the iteration or not. In case of `synchronizedMap`, you may invoke `forEach`, which will acquire the right lock for the entire iteration.

Comment: @Holger can you point to official documentation saying that `forEach` will acquire the lock. I will update the answer with that as well.

Comment: @tsolakp the official documentation does not specify that for any method. So if you want to restrict yourself to only explicitly mentioned methods, `synchronizedMap` becomes pointless.